# Group isomorphic to (Z,+)

Tags: group-theory

Please I beg help on this one. Even the first case its hard for me to prove
Consider $a\in\Bbb R$ such that $a \ne 0,1,-1$ and let $H=\{a^n \mid n\in\Bbb Z\}$. Show that $(H,\cdot)$ is a group isomorphic to $(Z,+)$.I find that a^n.b^n =(a.b)^n is also in H, also associativity holds, identity =a^0, also (a^n )^(-1)=(a^(-1) )^n Therefore H is a group. But to show H is isomorphic to (Z,+) I stuck on how to show the homomorphism exist.

Comment: Hint: the mapping that takes $n$ to $a^n$ is an isomorphism. The proof uses familiar laws of exponents.

Comment: am still thinking how can organize it @ Mike, Thanks @ Andre

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! New users are recommended to browse the "help" pages via the link in the upper right by the "search" field. In particular, we recommend you read the "asking" help pages at http://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking. You are likely to receive more prompt and targeted responses if you tell us how you've attempted to solve the problem, and where you are getting stuck.

Answer (score 1):

***Hints.***

Step 1.  Define $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \left\{a^n|n\in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$ by $\phi(n)=a^n$.

Step 2. Prove that $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

Step 3.  Show that $a^n= a^0=1$ implies that $n=0$.  This gives us injectivity, right?  Why?  (think kernels.)

Step 4.  Prove surjectivity.  Which element of $\mathbb{Z}$ is sent to $a^n$ under $\phi$ for an arbitrary $n$?

Comment: Thanks that gives me hope @Alxander